# .click to perform an insert query from a grid and a dropdown with asp.net and vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to perform the following function but I am having problems, no errors appear in my code but the table does not update when clicked.

When the user logs in and are redirected to the user.aspx page on a session a grid appears with their own medication from a link table - (holding medicineId from medicine and patientId from patient).

When the user selects their medicine from the gridview and chooses a pharmacy from the pharmacy drop down then clicks the btnconfirm button it should insert into the order_pres table - I have included a picture with steps of this.

I will include both my code from user.aspx and user.aspx.vb to provide understanding of the page as a whole and the function:

**User.aspx**

```
 'Grid to select medicine from:
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  >
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="UpdateMedicine" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MedicineId") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrcutions" HeaderText="Instructions" />
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<br />

    ' Holds the Pharmacy name from pharmacy 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPharm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurgeryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Pharmname FROM Pharmacy "></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />

  ' shows the pharmay name from pharmacy (there are 3 pharmacies in table)
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="Pharmname"></asp:DropDownList>
```

'button to perform the insert query after selections have been made

**User.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Imports System.Data

Partial Class Pages_user
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'shows grid when on session with the user that loggs in
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT md.MedicineId, md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions  " +
                                    "FROM Patient pt INNER JOIN prescription pr ON pt.PatientId = pr.PatientId  " +
                                    "INNER JOIN medicine md ON md.MedicineId = pr.MedicineId Where pt.PatientId  = @PatientId"
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
'select command for grid
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    lbldrop.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then
        Session("MedicineID") = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

    Dim PatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId").ToString
    Dim PharmacyId As Integer = Session("PharmacyId").ToString
    Dim DateOrdered As Date
    Dim MedicineId As Integer = Session("MedicineID")


    ' Get DoctorId from the patient table


    Dim DoctorId As String = "SELECT DoctorId FROM Patient  "

    'add PatientId, DoctorId, MedicineId, PharmacyId and date ordered to Order_pres table 

        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"



        Dim sqlCs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SurgeryConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCs),
              comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            With comm.Parameters

            .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PatientId").ToString
            .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("DoctorId").ToString
            .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("Medicine").ToString
            .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOrdered)

            End With

            Try
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                lblconfirm.Text() = "Order Placed"
            Catch ex As SqlException
                lblnoconfirm.Text() = "Order not placed"
            End Try
        End Using
```

The sessions in the log in page:

```
 Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            Session("Username") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))
            Session("DoctorId") = CStr(reader.Item("DoctorId"))
            found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
        End While
```

What the user page currently looks like and the steps:

[image: steps]

I am sorry for the amount of information I have provided but I thought it was essential to include for understanding of the question, hopefully someone else may spot where I am going wrong

Comment: Catching an exception and write to a label "Order not placed" is not very smart. The exception has a Message property that tells you what is wrong in your query. Change that code and write the Exception.Message and tell us what is the error message. I bet on a missing parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your query with 5 parameters placeholders, but you add only 4 parameters and try to update only 4 fields.
This should trigger an exception about a parameter missing.

But your code hides this problem swallowing the exception and just writing a message to your user (and to you as programmer that has no clue on what is going wrong).

So supposing that you want to update all 5 fields with 5 parameters your query could be something like this

```
Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

    Dim PatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId").ToString
    Dim PharmacyId As Integer = Session("PharmacyId").ToString
    Dim DateOrdered As Date ' ??? where do you initialize this value ????
    Dim MedicineId As Integer = Session("MedicineID")
    Dim DoctorId As String

    ' Get DoctorId from the patient table
    ' here put the code that initializes the DoctorID variable
    ' something like ... DoctorId = GetDoctorId() ...

     Dim query As String = String.Empty
     query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, MedicineID, PharmacyId,"
     query &= "                        DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
     query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"

      Dim sqlCs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SurgeryConnectionString").ConnectionString

      Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCs),
             comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
          With comm.Parameters

            .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patientID
            .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PharmacyID
            .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DoctorId
            .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MedicineID
            .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOrdered)

         End With
         Try
             conn.Open()
             Dim rowInserted = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
             if rowInserted = 1 Then 
                  lblconfirm.Text = "Order Placed"
             else
                  lblnoconfirm.Text = "Order not placed"
             End If
         Catch ex As SqlException
             lblnoconfirm.Text = "Unexpectd error: " & ex.Message
         End Try
     End Using

 End Sub
```

Note that all of your fields (except the Date Ordered) are of type integer, so when using AddWithValue don't convert these values to a string. This force the database engine to convert them back to an integer and this is a possible cause of problems (better use the Add method for the parameters collection specifying the exact type of the parameter)

Finally, the ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows inserted (or deleted or updated) by the query. So a return different of 0 a clear signal that your query has not worked)

Comment: Hi Steve :) thank you for taking the time to answer this, you are very kind. I will apply the changes now and see If I can get it to work - as for the pharmacy id  (from the drop down +sql data source) i am getting the following error for pharmacyId - I have not set a session on it from the login page would that be the problem? this happens when debugging : `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_05nd1l4n.dll but was not handled in user code `

Comment: Well, of course, if this value has not been set before reaching the update code the error is exactly the one you see. However for the purpose of testing this code you could simply initialize the variables with some fake values and click the button. If everything goes well then you could concentrate your efforts on the correct initialization of the Session variables.

Comment: Steve - from the way I am trying to add the pharmacyid from the drop down (this selects distinct name from the pharmacy table - as you can see in the datasource in user.aspx code  - I am disokaying the name on the drop down but how can I use the dropdown to select the pharmacy correctly?

Comment: also where will I call te session for pharmacyid - in the login.aspx.vb page like the rest of the sessions shown above (these are stored on login)

Comment: @laurajs please post a new question focused on the session problem. Shifting focus on another problem in comments is not helpful and just confusing. My answer is centered on the clear parameters problem. If you post a new and detailed question on the session problem more people are able to help you